# Should I do registration of medical images even when I am using deep learning?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, registration, image-segmentation, medical

I have 100 patients MRIs, and I am working on semantic segmentation of medical images.

I would like to ask experts, whether is it mandatory to do registration (before sending to the networks) even if I am using `deep learning techniques` and `convolutional neural networks`?

I am not familiar with registration, which tool are you suggesting? I have two datasets, one data format is `.mat` format and the other in `.mhd` format (each has 100 patients MRIs).

Your expert opinion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which type of MRI do you have?

MRIs usually have different time points, which means that many acquisition of the same volume are acquired, and because patients move, you must perform registration of the volumes.

For image registration, I use TurboReg for affine and translation, or you can use drop for elastic deformations.

For the deep learning part, if the network input is a single image/volume, then you don't need to perform registration.

Comment: T1 MRIs are the one that I am using. I am sending a 2d slice of volumes into the network in each forward pass. Could you please introduce a registration tool? and how registration can be done for 100 patients. which one should be source and fixed and others can be registered to that?

Comment: Thank you for helping. In the first dataset, the number of slices are varying patient to patient,  it  varies from 90 to 125 slices. But in the second dataset from another hospital. all patients' data has 60 slices.

Comment: The number of T1 slice depend on the object dimensions to acquire. Do you have different time points? You have time points when you use contrast enhancement product, like for breast tumors. If you have time points, you must register the time points together if you want to extract specific features like PK maps. However, if your goal is only segmentation of 2D slices, then you don't need registration. However if you work in 3D, then you need to register the 2D slices together. But no need to do if between patient.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you mean from `time points` that there may be different scans of one patient in different duration? If so, no my data is only related to different patients (inter-subject). What if, we have intra-subject data? should I register in that case? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's what I meant. When you use a contrast agent, you do the same acquisition for the same patient in order to observe the agent spreading in the tumor.